# django include block partial view

Tags: python, django

I have this `1.html` view:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>this is h1</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

And I want to have another partial view: 
For example
I have file `somefile.html`

in this file I have following html:

```
<p>Text in somefile.html</p>
```

How do I include `somefile.html` in `1.html` view ?

Comment: I think you are looking for the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>this is h1</h1>

    {% include "somefile.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```